How to get images in real time when MR scaning using SCU/SCP
We use multi-frames series to scan in MR。but when using dcmsend（dcmtk tool) to recv images， we can't get any image until the series scan finished.
Is any way to get image when the series is scaning ?  Or any parameter in MR server need to set?
For example, In file directory, get 1 frame image in 1s, get 2 frame image in 2s ... and so on.
